# QGIS2threejs scale bar and north arrow

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I am wondering is it possible to have scale bar and north arrow in 3D view when viewing in browser and also when saving image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not super practical but It is possible.

Use View -> Decorations enable north arrow and scale bar. When you create 3d model it will "burn" Decorations on the surface.

Answer (score 3):

If they do not have to be too pretty, you could create them as a layer(s) that could be exported to Q3JS. Bear in mind that a scale bar would be a bit misleading due to perspective distortion of distances